# Change the Tag of a library in JFrog

Tags: tags, jfrog-cli

Is there a way to change, or update, the tag of a library stored on JFrog?
Or it just has to be replaced?
I could not find any API reference for a method that updates the artifact information on JFrog

Comment: You can overwrite. 
Binaries are immutable by definition. In my opinion, if you change a library, it means it is no longer the same library/version.